# How to parse multiple times in python

Tags: python, split

I'm trying to parse a string read from a txt file.
The line is :

```
(0 ,3) :5.0|(1 ,3) : -5.0
```

I need to firstly get (0,3) then 5, after splitting with "|" I need to get (1,3) and -5

**At the end,** I should have 2 list variable that holds the values seperately.
The first list should have : (0,3) and (1,3)
The second list should hold : 5,-5

What I tried:

```
goal_states, their_reward = lines[5].split("|"), lines[5].rsplit(':', 1)
```

What I get : `['(0,3):5.0|(1,3)', '-5.0']`

Thank you in advance

P.S: I shouldn't use any import statement.

Comment: Are the tuples always unique?

Comment: @Sayse yes they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is what you want.

```py
s = "(0 ,3) :5.0|(1 ,3) : -5.0"

def get_result(s: str) -> tuple:
    goals = []
    rewards = []
    
    for pair in s.split("|"):
        goal, reward = pair.split(":")

        goals.append(eval(goal.strip()))
        rewards.append(float(reward.strip()))

    return (goals, rewards)

print(get_result(s))
```

Answer (score 2):

`literal_eval` method that @Sayse used is of course the straight forward way of doing it. But if you want to do a little bit of parsing you can do:

```py
txt = "(0 ,3) :5.0|(1 ,3) : -5.0"
txt = txt.replace(" ", "")

goal_states = []
their_rewards = []
for i in txt.split('|'):  # ['(0,3):5.0', '(1,3):-5.0']
    a, b = i.split(':')
    _, n1, _, n2, _ = a    # `a` is something like '(0,3)'

    n1 = int(n1)
    n2 = int(n2)

    goal_states.append((n1, n2))
    their_rewards.append(int(float(b)))

print(goal_states)
print(their_rewards)
```

output:

```
[(0, 3), (1, 3)]
[5, -5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the pipe to a comma, then format it as a dictionary and use ast's `literal_eval` to give yourself a dictionary to work with

```
  import ast
  s = "(0 ,3) :5.0|(1 ,3) : -5.0"
  s = s.replace("|", ",")
  ast.literal_eval(f"{{{s}}}")
```

```
{(0, 3): 5.0, (1, 3): -5.0}
```

Comment: thank you for your response but we are not allowed to use any import statement. This is my bad, I'm so sorry. Is it possible to do this without import?

Comment: Those floats should also be converted to int (as OP asked for 5 and -5)

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary The self answer the op gave didn't appear to require them to be different data types

Comment: @Sayse Yes but that is his/her *failed try* :D

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with list comprehension:

For example:

```
string = "(0, 3): 5.0|(1 ,3) : -5-0"
parsed_list1, parsed_list2 = [i.split(":") for i in string.split("|")]

print(parsed_list1)
print(parsed_list2)
```

Output:

['(0, 3)', ' 5.0']

['(1 ,3) ', ' -5-0']

Comment: But the OP asked for tuples and integers. They are just strings in your final result.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this performing multiple split operation.

```
goal_states=[]
their_obstacles=[]
for i in "(0 ,3) :5.0|(1 ,3) : -5.0".split("|"):
   goal_states.append(i.split(":")[0])
   their_obstacles.append(i.split(":")[1])
```

Comment: There are lots of extra spaces in your final result